# Delete row using jquery by pressing button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a code which adds rows dynamically into a cart. Their is delete button in front of every row to delete that row. When the user press button the parent of that button should be grabbed and then implement remove() method to remove that row. But this way its not working for me.. Can anybody tell me where i am doing wrong? Following is my code

```
      <div class="container" id="dynamic">
                 <div class="row " id="main-row">
                   <div class="col-sm-1  " id="serial">1</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2  ">
                    <select class="container-fluid">
                        <option value="1">Computer</option>
                        <option value="2">Mobile</option>
                        <option value="3">LCD</option>
                        <option value="4">Keyboard</option>
                        <option value="5">Mouse</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
         <div class="col-sm-2 "><input class="length" type="number" min="1"          name="name" value="" /></div>
          <div class="col-sm-2 "><input class="length" type="text" name="text"      value="" min="1" /></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><input class="length" type="text" min="1"/></div>
                <button class="btn-primary col-sm-1 del ">Delete</button>
             </div>

          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" id="button1">Add Row</button>
        </section>
```

Here is my jquery code.

```
 //code for adding rows dynamically
 var counter = 1;
$(function () {

$("#button1").click(function () {
    counter++;
    $('#dynamic').append($("#main-row").clone().attr("id",counter-1));
    $("#serial").text(counter);

     });
 });
   //code for deleting row
  $('.del').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
   });
```

Comment: Please somebody answer me as i am stuck here at this point. I have tried couple of different things but nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're adding the rows dynamically, you'll need to use a [delegated event handler](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Also use `this` instead of `".del"` to avoid deleting all the rows.

```
$(document).on('click', '.del', function () {
  $(this).parent().remove();
 });
```

Otherwise, the new `.del` objects will not get the the click event.

Comment: The button is not working. even if i changed .del to this.. There is no error on console as well

Comment: Nothing happen by pressing button. It don't delete the row

Comment: Does it delete the row in my Snippet?  If so, we'll need to see more of your code.

Comment: Yes it is deleting in your snippet

Comment: please see the updated question. I have added the code of dynamically adding row. I think that might be one which is causing delete button not to work.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: are you here? Please reply